# REST APIs using RAML and API-Kit on MuleESB 3.6?

Tags: api, rest, mule, mule-studio

I would like to know if deploying APIs designed using RAML and API-kit in the studio on Mule Enterprise Server for ESB ver. 3.6 is a good idea?

Our organization is interested in using Mule ESB 3.6 for integrations and we thought of recommending using RAML and API-kit for REST API design and development. We are not interested in any Gateway features but would like to leverage RAML for API definition.

Has anyone experienced any issues if we go for a Mule ESB 3.6 Enterprise and deploy these REST APIs designed using API-Kit and RAML there? Is this design approach specifically meant for the API Gateway which is part of the Mule Any-point API Product offering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Gateway (AGW) is a superset of Mule EE. RAML and APIKit are not tightly coupled to API Gateway or Mule ESB but can work in either of them. In the case of AGW, APIKit comes bundled with it, while with Mule ESB you have to provide the jar yourself or develop your APIKit project on Mule Studio (using the APIKit Mule Studio plugin) and export the project from Mule Studio when ready.

The advantage of using AGW is that you can develop your APIKit project as usual, and then be able to apply-unapply high end policies to it at runtime (OAuth security, XML Threat protection, IP Blacklisting, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem in doing what you are suggesting. Gateway and such are services build on top of Mule and RAML technologies -- if you choose not to use them you'll just lose the features they offer but again RAML, Mule, and APIkit work just fine on their own!

Answer (score 0):

I have used this REST API using RAML for my client. They didn't face any issues and it's working perfectly.  And it's easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version of mule brought many features like api auto discovery and there is no separate gateway and runtime they have been combined together as a single component.
Api auto discovery allows us to apply policies on top of original implementation api.

you can create proxy for the original implementation and policies can be applied on the proxy layer which is in gateway.